# Azure Application Gateway WAF V2 redirect request

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I would like to implement a redirect rule on my Application Gateway v2 where the request from the root or default path will redirect to `/api/dyn`.

Example: `https://myagw.com   ->   https://myagw.com/api/dyn`

Checked the Application Gateway Redirection, could not work with any solution.

In the HTTP Sever, I have used the following mod rewrite, trying to achieve same in the Application gateway V2

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /api/dyn/ [redirect=301]
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, You can Implement a redirect rule on my Application Gateway v2 where the request from the root or default path will redirect to `/api/dyn`.

I have created application v2 with default rule, listener backend pool, and Http setting

You can create a basic rule With a path-based backend HTTP setting that corresponds to the root path (/) and a default backend HTTP setting that corresponds to the /api/dyn path. This setting uses the default HTTP setting to forward requests that match the root path to the default backend pool, which will direct the request to the /api/dyn path.

***In Application gateway -> routing rule -> add your backend pool and backend target and select add multiple path target to path based rule***

[image]

Type target type as /api/dyn. Add your backend target and backend setting like below:

[image]

Add a health probe with your custom host and path with backend setting like below:

[image]

Now, when I try to check my URL it redirects successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[azure-docs/configuration-request-routing-rules.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules.md)